# Problems with displaying data from tables into Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a ms-access database that allows an edit function of data within the tables. This is done by displaying a form that has data retrieved from the tables so it is easier to read and edit.

My colleague was messing around with the default values on the property sheet (layout view) of the text boxes. 
Now the edit function does not retrieve data from the tables unless I open it twice. So first time i click edit the edit form has no data but if I go back to and click edit again the form is filled with the relevant data.

I cannot figure out what she did to make this happen and how to resolve this issue. I have a backup of the database and the their are no differences to the underlying back-end and only difference is tab indexes which is because the tables are different in each version.

Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Best way to get help is to show your code

Comment: Its not really an issue with the code because the backup and normal db have exactly the same code, just the normal one doesn't do the retrieval properly first time around. I'll post the code when i get a chance.

Comment: @dbmitch I have added the code.

Comment: Can't you just import the old form from your backup database then?

Comment: @dbmitch don't know how that never crossed my mined, it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Excellent - glad it was an easy fix - much better than going thru all the form and control properties